# App Script to to add Section Header into another column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet where each row has a header (+) expanding into sub-rows. I want to extract header column value into another column.It's like getting all parent section into another column.I need to write an AppScript for that I believe. Could somebody help on this?

I have tried several AppScripts but it's not working

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have a google sheet where each row has a header (+) expanding into sub-rows. I want to extract header column value into another column.It's like getting all parent section into another column.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: They say a picture is worth a thousand words.  Can you imagine making a gif video that's less than 2 MB.  I think it would be helpful to me to help visualize what currently only exist in your mind.